# Merge two arrays and loop through them to return all the elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have two queries that return 5 rows of data from each query. I then merge the resulting arrays to create one array.

If I were using just one arry I would do it like this:

```
mysql_select_db($database_iMaint, $iMaint);
$query_WaterHot = sprintf("SELECT h.UniqueID, h.Room, h.AuditBy,  h.AuditDate, h.SeqID, h.WaterHot 
FROM NXLHR_Hist h 
WHERE (h.WaterHot IS NOT NULL OR
       h.WaterHot IS NOT NULL
      ) 
      AND 
      h.CompStamp >=  DATE('".$_POST['FromDate']."') 
      AND 
      h.CompStamp <= DATE('".$_POST['ToDate']."') 
ORDER BY h.Room ASC 
");
$WaterHot = mysql_query($query_WaterHot, $iMaint) or die(mysql_error());
$row_WaterHot = mysql_fetch_assoc($WaterHot);
$totalRows_WaterHot= mysql_num_rows($WaterHot);


do {

    echo $row_WaterHot['Room'];
    echo $row_WaterHot['WaterHot'];
    echo $row_WaterHot['WaterCold'];

} while ($row_WaterHot = mysql_fetch_assoc($WaterHot));
```

Above is how I would normally process the data but in this case I am using the results from two queries which is why I am merging them.

So I now need to loop through the merged array and output each of the values.

```
$row_WaterHot = mysql_fetch_assoc($Waterhot); // five records
$row_WaterCold = mysql_fetch_assoc($WaterCold); // five records
$Water = array();
$Water = array_merge($row_WaterHot, $row_WaterCold);

foreach ($Water as $key => $value) {

// how do I echo the results of each value like this
echo "the name of the $key and the $value

}
```

Or should I be doing this another way?

Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Comment: With `foreach`?

Comment: Hint: With `mysql_fetch_assoc()` you only fetch one row each time.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.foreach.php)
This is pretty easy to use. The template looks like this :

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
}
```

In your case, you would have something like this

```
  foreach($Water as $key=>$val)
        echo $val;
```

Comment: When I write the "foreach($Water as $key=>$val) echo $val" how would I use the name of each $key and the $val so I can display them. Again thanks for your time.

Comment: `echo " $key$val";`

Comment: For example, if $key is "name" and value ="Alexis". Then, you could output both values like this : echo "His $key is $val"; This would output "His name is Alexis"

Comment: Don't hesitate to accept this answer if it helped you @DCJones :)